# JavaScript algorithm: is there a way to sort an already sorted array with the absolute values of its elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I got this question during an interview.

I have an array that contains both negative and positive integers that are already sorted e.g.
`const array = [-5, -3, 0, 2,7]`

I am trying to write a function to sort the array using the absolute values of its elements. So the sorted array would be `[ 0, 2, 3, 5, 7 ]`

Here is my attempt

```js
function sortArrayWithAbsoluteValue(array) {
    const result = array.map(num => Math.abs(num)).sort((a,b) => a - b)
    return result
}
```

Apparently, this works but it doesn't take advantage of the fact that the array is already sorted . Is there a better or more clever/efficient way to sort this?

Comment: Use two iterators. Start one iterator from left and the other from right. Take the value with max absolute value and go to the next

Comment: @ThomasSablik care to write up an answer with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let two indexes move towards eachother from either ends of the input array and based on how they compare, you copy the absolute value to the target array, filling it from end to front:

```js
function absSorted(array) {    
    let result = Array(array.length);
    for (let k = array.length - 1, i = 0, j = k; k >= 0; k--) {
        result[k] = Math.abs(array[-array[i] < array[j] ? j-- : i++]);
    }
    return result;
}

const array = [-5, -3, 0, 2, 7];
console.log(absSorted(array));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I wonder if there is a way to do this in place without extra space complexity?

Comment: Sure, but it will then it will not be possible to stick with a linear time complexity.

Comment: @trincot Why not? Can't we use an linear time constant space merge algorithm?

Comment: I don't see that is possible, as the permutation to perform involves cycles of varying sizes. It seems to me we lose the benefit of the original organisation of the data and fall back to a normal comparison sort.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest solution is to introduce a new array and simply unshift it with elements from the first array

```
const array = [-9, -8, -5, -3, -2, 0, 2,7];
const newArray = [];
let i = 0, j = array.length - 1;

while(i <= j) {
  const first = Math.abs(array[i]);
  const last = Math.abs(array[j]);
  if(first > last){
    newArray.unshift(first)
    i++;
  }
  else {
    newArray.unshift(last)
    j--;
  }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

But this solution could be challenged by interviewers as unshift operator is slow `o(n)` so we can create newArray with the same size as array and then simply fill it in a similar way

```
const array = [-9, -8, -5, -3, -2, 0, 2,7];
const newArray = new Array(array.length);
let i = 0, j = array.length - 1, l = array.length - 1;

while(i <= j) {
  const first = Math.abs(array[i]);
  const last = Math.abs(array[j]);
  if(first > last){
    newArray[l] = first;
    i++;
  }
  else {
    newArray[l] = last;
    j--;
  }
  l--;
}

console.log(newArray)
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I wonder if there is a way to do this in place without extra space complexity?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two iterators. One iterator starts from left and the other from right. Since the array is sorted one iterator points to the max absolute value. Store this value in a new array and iterate that iterator

```js
const array = [-5, -3, 0, 2,7]

function f(array) {
    let i = 0;
    let j = array.length - 1;
    const newArray = [];
    while (i <= j) {
        if (Math.abs(array[i]) < Math.abs(array[j])) {
            newArray.push(Math.abs(array[j]));
             --j;
        } else {
            newArray.push(Math.abs(array[i]));
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(f(array));
```

You can start at the min values with the inverted logic to get an increasing sort:

```js
const array = [-5, -3, 0, 2, 7]

function g(array) {
    
    let j = 0;
    while (j < array.length && array[j] < 0) {
        ++j;
    }
    let i = j - 1;
    const newArray = [];
    while (i >= 0 && j < array.length) {
        if (Math.abs(array[i]) < Math.abs(array[j])) {
            newArray.push(Math.abs(array[i]));
             --i;
        } else {
            newArray.push(Math.abs(array[j]));
            ++j;
        }
    }
    if (i >= 0) {
        newArray.push(...array.slice(0, i + 1).reverse().map(el => -el));
    }
    if (j < array.length) {
        newArray.push(...array.slice(j));
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(g(array));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but it doesn't return `[ 0, 2, 3, 5, 7 ]` tho. it is reversed. I guess you have to change `push` to `unshift` but `unshift` takes o(n) since you need to shift the array around.

Comment: @Joji I added another algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

I converted all the numbers to the absolute value first using `map`

Then using a while loop, I used the `indexOf` and `Math.min` functions and the `spread` operator (`...`) to find the index of the minimum number of the array

Then I removed that from the array using `splice`

```js
const array = [-5, -3, 0, 2,7];

function resort(array) {
  const newArray = [];
  array = array.map(i => Math.abs(i));
  while (array.length) {
    const minIndex = array.indexOf(Math.min(...array));
    newArray.push(array.splice(minIndex, 1)[0]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(resort(array));
```